# Simperium - Diff errors, UniCharMax

Tags: ios, simperium

I'm serializing an array of dictionaries to a string and it seems that it causes issues on the generation of the diff… or something… I've been seeing a lot of these:

```
AssertMacros: hash <= (~(UniChar)0x00), Hash value has exceeded UniCharMax! file: /Users/…/Pods/Google-Diff-Match-Patch/DiffMatchPatchCFUtilities.c, line: 391
```

I didn't look very deep but I didn't understood what am I doing wrong…

Also, I'm having a lot of 440 errors that sometimes appear with the error above. How can I handle these errors? Shouldn't the framework send the full object when the 440 pops up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error 440 means 'Invalid Diff'. After checking DiffMatchPatch, it seems that the error you're seeing is caused by an excesively large array of diffs (which, in this case, seems to be a Diff Match Patch internal issue).

Please, take a look at this pull request, which already implements the mechanism you're currently working on: https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/pull/121

Specifically, NSArray+Simperium, SPMemberJsonList and SPJsonDiff contain logic to handle DiffMatchPatch.